# $\langle R,+,.\rangle$ Ring prove or disprove

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Prove or disprove 
Let $\langle R,+,\cdot\rangle $ be a ring and $a,b \in R$.

1. If $a\cdot b=0$ then $a=0$ or $b=0$
2. If $a\cdot a=a$ then $a=1$ or $a= 0$   if  $(1\in R)$

I think that '1.' is a false statement.

Counterexample:
$\langle Z,+,.\rangle$ is a ring with $a\cdot b=a+b,\,\,\forall a ,b \in R$, where $a=1$ and $b=-1$ then $a\cdot b=1+(-1)=0$. But $a$ and $b$ don't equal zero.

Is that true? And what about the second one?

Comment: I took the liberty of reformatting your problem statement.  Can you please edit and insert the work you've done on the problem so far?

Answer (score 2):

Both are false. Take as $R$ the ring of $2\times2$ matrices with integer coefficients.

1. $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right).\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, but $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)\neq\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.
2. $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right).\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, but $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)\notin\left\{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right),\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)\right\}$.

Comment: That's what I need thank you (+1)

Answer (score 2):

One nice counterexample is the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. In that ring, we have $[2]\cdot [3]=[0]$ and $[3]\cdot [3]=[3]$.

I'm puzzled by the counterexample you provided in your question. It's not true that $\langle\mathbb{Z},+,\cdot\rangle$ is a ring if you redefine multiplication to be addition. Multiplication has to be the operation that distributes over the other operation.

Answer (score 1):

1. The first is asking about [zero divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor). In particular it asks if all rings are integral domains. This is of course not the case. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain#Non-examples).
2. The second is asking about [idempotents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_(ring_theory)). In an integral domain, the only idempotents are the additive identity $0$ and the multiplicative identity $1$. Outside of an integral domain, this is not necessarily the case.

Indeed, a non-trivial idempotent (nontrivial not equal to $0$ or $1$) is a zero divisor. Let $a\in R$ be a nontrivial idempotent, so that $a^2=a$. Then $$a(a-1)=a^2-a=a-a=0.$$ So $a^2$ and $a-1$ are zero divisors (unless $a=0$ or $a=1$).